# how to select a class or id when a button is clicked with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My div with class="vote" is

```
<div class="vote">
<input type="hidden" name="q_id" class="q_id" id="q_id" q_id="{{ result.object.id }}" value="{{ result.object.id }}">
<button type="submit" class="downvote" value="downvote">downvote</button>
```

and there are several divs of this type on my html page,

My ajax call with jquery is

```
$('.downvote').click(function() {
var q_id=$(this).attr('q_id')
console.log(q_id)
$.ajax( {
    type: 'GET',
    url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/q/downvote/",
    data:q_id,
    success: searchSuccessDown,
    dataType: 'html'
});
});
function searchSuccessDown(data) {
console.log('downvoted successfully');}
```

I am newbee and my question is when a downvote button is clicked(there are several downvote buttons on the page) how to select input tag with id="q_id" or class="q_id" for the corresponding div with class="vote" and pass its value through ajax data.

Comment: You mean you want to post the input data to the url through ajax?? and in return do you want to get any data or not???

Comment: You should add `event.preventDefault();` to your JS code in order to prevent the form from submitting and also you are not using a form to do it..! so make it form also..!

Comment: Does your div with vote class contains only 2 elements??

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai - only when it's relevant. In OP's case, nothing will *submit* so it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Marcus : Yes indeed but it's nor proper way to do it or is it???

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Well, it depends on the scenario. There is no need to *prevent* default behaviour when it's not necessary. In doing so, you incite question into what behaviour is being suppressed. So if I come in as a developer later on, and you've scattered `e.preventDefault()` everywhere for no good reason, it makes things confusing for me as I'm trying to tie that event to something that isn't actually there. Since OP's `button` has no `action` (ie. within a form from what I can see) there is no need for it. However, if OP's button *does* submit a form, then you might be right.

Comment: @Marcus : As you wish..Friend..! :D

Comment: Just remember, OP only states that he/she has a `div`, not a `form`. There is no default behaviour to suppress when enclosed within a `div` :)

Comment: I am not submitting form, just sending data through ajax call @Umair Shah Yousafzai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to get the parent element (which is the vote div), then find the q_id element inside that:

```
var q_id = $(this).parent().find('.q_id').val();
```

Here's a quick fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1m56g6jL/

Answer (score 1):

Here is exactly how you should be doing it :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="vote">
<form method="post" action="" id="downvote_form">
<input type="hidden" name="q_id" class="q_id" id="q_id" q_id="{{ result.object.id }}" value="{{ result.object.id }}">
<button type="submit" class="downvote" value="downvote">downvote</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#downvote_form').on('submit', function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/q/downvote/',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data) {
                            if (data == "success") {
                                console.log(data);
                                window.location.href = "success.php"; //=== Show Success Message==
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            alert("You have an error); //===Show Error Message====
                            }
                        }); e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
                });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
...click(function (e) {

var qIdNode = $(e.target)
.closest(".vote") // navigates to the closest parent that have the class vote
.find('.q_id'); // then finds the sibling q_id element of the target/clicked element...

});
```